# How To Solve IIS Giving HTTP Error 500.19?

Tags: c#, xml, web-config, asp.net-core-2.0

I have website which I am trying to run through IIS. But on browsing the website it shows error saying

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

[image]

Below is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
   <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
    <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
  </handlers>
  <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\AlphaWeb.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
</system.webServer>
</location>
</configuration>
```

I am on Windows10, IIS 10.0.18362.1

Comment: @Fildor Windows10, IIS 10.0.18362.1

Comment: I added that to the question.

Comment: The users have no access to the IIS file system.  User only have GUEST privilege.  You would need to have app run as admin which is not recommended.  May be put the files on a network drive with privileged that allows GUEST accounts to read and write.

Comment: Are you trying to host this as a virtual app under another app?